# Counterexample to: If odd Taylor coefficients for g in a=0 equals 0, then g is an even function.

Tags: taylor-expansion, examples-counterexamples, even-and-odd-functions

Let g be an infinitely differentiable function.

Find counterexample to: If the odd Taylor coefficients for g in a=0 equals 0, then g is an even function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are infinitely differentiable functions which are not equal to their Taylor expansions (except at $x=0$).  For instance:

$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2}  & \text{if $x>0$} \\
0 & \text{if $x≤0$}
\end{cases}$$

This has a Taylor expansion which is identically $0$ but the function is not even.